# Python installing package with pip failed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, twisted

I got this error message when I was installing python-binance.
Error message is in the link below please check
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VE0Ux_ji9RoK0NIrPD3BSbs60sTaxThk3boxsvh051c/edit
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install [`email` from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/email/) which is a very old outdated Python2-only package.

`email` is now [a module in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html). You don't need to install it, it must always be available. Just import and use.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I encounter this problem every time I try to install a new package.

Comment: @tomohiroluo Can we see an error with a different package, not from stdlib?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VE0Ux_ji9RoK0NIrPD3BSbs60sTaxThk3boxsvh051c/edit?usp=sharing    There's the link to error message installing python-binance

Answer (score -1):

You might have outdated setuptools, try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then continue trying to install the module you want.

Usually these kinds of problems can be solved by googling the error: in this case you should try searching with "python setup.py egg_info".

Also, try to give a more descriptive title for your problems in the future. "Python installing package with pip failed" is too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys I already figured out what error message means, I downloaded twisted from third party website and installed it and it worked.